# What does "BP Drive 2" mean?

Tags: dell-poweredge

I've got a Dell PowerEdge 2850 server.  The display on its front panel says, "BP Drive 2" and that display has an amber color.  What does "BP Drive 2" mean?

Comment: shouldn't this fall under rtfm?  Down voting it.

Answer (score 7):

"BP Drive 2" means there's a fault with drive ID "2" attached to the BackPlane.

My guess would be that you have a RAID 5 array on that server, and one of the drives have failed.  Sometimes it's a fault that can be corrected by rebuilding the drive through the PERC BIOS, sometimes pulling the drive out and putting it back will correct it, but most often, the drive's dead.  (Checking the PERC BIOS will give you a better idea, and you should check before doing anything). In all likelihood, it's time to get a new drive before the array fails and you lose your data.

Answer (score 2):

That would most probably be the drive in slot 2 (with BP being short from Back Plane). If you can still log into server, start Dell Server administrator, you should see more detailed info.